# HTML5 video controls not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, html, internet-explorer, video

I'm having a little trouble with IE11 (and 10 and 9, when simulated through IE11's f12->Emulation menu) in that the controls for HTML5 videos are not working. The video displays, and if autoplay is enabled will even play, but it will not respond to play/pause, seek, fullscreen etc.

The page works fine in the latest chrome, safari, firefox browsers, just not IE.

Anyone able to help me? Link to live site is http://bslhomework.org.uk/christmas

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have tried with IE 11 on Windows 8.1 and the video is played after I hit the play button, although with some considerable delay the first time. I can also switch to full screen.

Comment: I'm on Win7 Pro 64bit, using IE11. Strange that it works for you, but not me. The delay is likely because the video is not preloaded (there are 26 videos on the page, didn't want to slow page loading).

Comment: It works for me in Win7.

Answer (score 0):

http://bslhomework.org.uk/christmas is unreachable (file not found).

http://bslhomework.org.uk/

is redirecting to [http]://127[dot]0[dot]0[dot]1 (bad)

do you still need help?

Comment: Sorry, 1and1 caused an issue. Site should be visible now.